# ContentProviderのquery処理にかかる時間を実用出来るレベルに短縮出来ないか試行錯誤しています。

Tags: android, android-asynctask

現在、5万件ほどのデータを保持しているテーブルから全件データ取得し、
取得したデータをリストに一覧表示する際にかかる時間を短縮出来ないか試行錯誤しています。

テストした実機は Galaxy Nexus AndroidOS:4.22 です。

試したのは、以下の３点です。

・AsyncTaskを複数使用する
→AsyncTaskのスレッド数が5個までで11タスク動かそうとしても上手くいかず、処理は完了しませんでした。(ログで確認しましたが、9タスクほど完了した時点で処理が終了してしまいました・・・)

・SELECT文の修正
→select * 〜 になっていたのを試しにデータのタイトルだけ取得するようにしましたが、それでもまだ約20秒から30秒ほど掛かってしまいます・・・

・contentProviderClientを使用
→僅かながら効果はありましたが、上記のSELECT文の修正をあわせて使っても実用性に欠ける結果となりました。

後残っているのは、
Twitterなどの様にListviewが終端までスクロールされた時に追加で読み込みをするしかないのかなと思っています。
ただ、これはこれで他の箇所への影響が多いため可能ならば回避したい所ではあります・・・

解決のヒントになるような些細な事でもいいので、
どうか回答よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 詳細な情報を追記していただくとより良い回答が得られるかもしれません。表示はListViewでしょうか？Adapterは何か使用されてますか？テーブルとだけ書いてありますがsqliteでしょうか？それとも何か外部ライブラリを使用されてますか？可能であれば現状のコードを提示されると認識を合わせやすくなります。

Comment: maot様
回答ありがとうございます。
コードも載せようとしたのですが、色々といじった後だったので今回はすみません・・・

以下、手順です。
・AsyncTaskによる非同期処理で、ContentPrivaider使用でDBからデータ取得

・取得したデータを配列にして、BaseAdapterを拡張したクラスに格納しListviewに表示

AsyncTaskを使用しているのは、LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacksだとCursorのデータ量が多すぎるというエラーが出たからです。

今回は、データ取得から配列に格納までかなり時間がかかっていましたが試しにCursorAdapterを使用すると実用可能範囲にまで速くなりましたのでこれを使ってみようと思います。

Comment: 解決されたようで何よりです。ボトルネックになっていたのはquery処理ではなく、query投げて取得したあとだったのですね。タイトルを少し修正した方がこれから同じ問題を解決される方の役にたつかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)で扱えば件数は関係なくListViewなどに表示できると思います。

Comment: [CursorAdapterの基本 - Boring Days as tech](http://boring-days.hatenablog.com/entry/20100921/1285086144)
こちらのブログが参考になるかと思います。

Comment: shikajiro様　私が投稿したコメントにも書いたのですが、回答頂いたCursorAdapterでどうにかいけそうです。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

試されたことのみ記載されていて、どのような構成で実装されているのかわかりませんでしたので、案のみ記載します。

1. １００件のデータを読み込む
2. 1.で読み込んだデータが０でなければ、次の１００件のデータを読み込む。
   1.で読み込んだデータが０ならば、読み込み終了
3. pause時には読み込み処理を停止
4. resume時には読み込み処理を再開

---

５万件を**一度に**取得する高速化のテクニックを求めているのであれば、回答になっていないかもしれません。